# Running c++ on cluster with slurm and sif container

Tags: c++, dockerfile, slurm, hpc, singularity-container

I'm attempting to execute a C++ code on a cluster that utilizes Slurm. Since the server did not have g++ installed, I created a Singularity container (SIF) to facilitate the execution. However, I've observed considerable variations in the runtime of the same executable after each run. For instance, the code takes 1.30 hours to complete on the first run and then 2.30 hours on the second run. The cause of these fluctuations is unclear to me. Do you have any suggestions or insights on why this might be occurring?

To address this concern, I've attempted to modify the optimization flags, optimize the code, and profile its performance. However, despite these efforts, the issue persists.

Comment: I assume the execution time diffs are for replicate runs, with the same program input and parameters?

Comment: yes for replicate runs, with the same program input and parameters

Comment: In your bash submission script to `sbatch` you can put (before running the Singularity/c++ program) things like 'env';  'cat /proc/cpuinfo'; `cat /proc/meminfo`. This is to check if the issue is not trivial, like different CPUs on different nodes.

Comment: I attempted to rerun the code on the same node, thereby utilizing the identical hardware resources.

Comment: another idea: if your program input/output or tmp_files are large enough there may be some IO differences if some other user process competes with yours. Since the run times are hours, you can ssh to the given node and check what else is running or explore `watch` command in the submission script

Comment: Could an overloaded server be responsible for the time difference? I use the input file only at the beginning of the code and then close it, and the output file corresponds to only a few lines.

Comment: Few lines of the output is nothing. To be on the safe side you may measure in your c++ code time needed to load the input file and print it out, so the `slurm-1234xyz.log` can catch it. If your program uses a lot of RAM and the computing node is swapping this can also slow you down.

Comment: If you can shrink the input/make the program run say 5x faster there is always profiling using i.e. `valgrind`. But this slows down the program a lot, and the executable should be compiled with debugging on.

Comment: I have previously measured the time to read the input, and it corresponds to just a few milliseconds. The program utilizes a maximum of 1GB of RAM, and the pre-allocated RAM in the SBATCH configuration file is set to 8GB

Comment: Running out of ideas: md5 checksums for the SIF image and executable binary in it and the input file.

Comment: the md5 checksums is the same

Comment: Sorry for asking the obvious which should be the first one: by "runtime" you mean "time from the moment the computing node started to run your job until it did finish"? If runtime == "time from submitting the job to SLURM until the finish" then there is no mystery: depending on cluster load and user/job priority such "runtimes" differ a lot between submissions.

Comment: I mean the time from the Moment the computing node started to run my job until it finish

Comment: You may check with your cluster admins if your SLURM cluster supports job suspension and if they have any info if your long running job got suspended. See i.e.: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71213790/731351